# html input readonly cut of the trailing text

Tags: html, css

The value of my readonly input element is being cut off.  Is there a way to correct this without changing the font type or font  size?  https://jsfiddle.net/hockchailim/tkg7a4c8/

```
<style>
input[readonly] {
  border: none;
  font-size: .85em;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  width: auto;
}
</style>
<input readonly="readonly" type="text" value="mmm.mmmm-mmmm@test.com">
```

Comment: Change the size of the input. Your only options are to change the font-size or input size. I would also suggest not attempting to set the width of the input based on it's value, that could lead to all sorts of weird situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change width to 100%

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count = $("#readonly").val().length;
    $("#readonly").css("width","calc("+ count +" * 0.85em)");
});
```

```css
input[readonly] {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 3px 0 3px 0;
    padding: 2px;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<input id="readonly" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="mmm.mmmm-mmmm@test.com">
```

Comment: so, there is no way to make it auto expand (like td)?

Comment: I removed the width and added jQuery that calculates the with according to the character count this way it will auto expand, I hope this helps:)

Answer (score 0):

Well... You don't want to change the font type/size? What about the input width? Getting `width:250px` instead of the auto width fixes the problem.